# Is it possible to efficiently add elements into an XML document on-the-fly?

Tags: c#, xml

What I mean by that title is that I am attempting to construct an XML file as records are being read from a database.  In a way, I guess you'd say I am doing a manual version of `DataSet.WriteToXML()`.  But I need to control the data as it flows through, hence the manual writing of records.

My problem is that no matter what I've tried to do with `XDocument`, with and without `Streams`, I find that the elements I add are simply piling up in memory.  Even when I try to "batch" the records and call an occasional `XDocument.Save()`, I still wind up with an `OutOfMemoryException` at some point.

So first off, I am wondering of there is any such thing as "read a record, write a record"...a straight-line pass through from a DataTable.Row to an XML Node/Sub-nodes (a record in XML).  Even though I suspect that any "yes" answer would come with a major performance penalty from all the I/O it would involve.

My latest iteration (there have been too many to list):

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.Indent = true;
using (var fs = new FileStream(tmpXml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(fs));
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    using (var reader = sql.ExecuteReader(String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM ""{0}""", dt.TableName)))
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var tableElement = new XElement(dt.TableName);
                xdoc.Root.Add(tableElement);
                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    if (dt.TableName.EndsWith("_Option") && reader.GetOrdinal(dc.ColumnName) == 13)
                        tableElement.Add(new XElement(dc.ColumnName, ""));
                    else
                        tableElement.Add(new XElement(dc.ColumnName, reader[dc.ColumnName]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the basic question is, what's the most efficient way to take the rows I read, and get them into the physical XML file as quickly as possible, preventing the XDocument from piling up data in memory?

EDIT:  I should point out that the XML file exists already, with only the table schema written to it.  The goal here is to open that file, write the actual data records to it, and save it.

Comment: What about using XmlWriter? It's just for writing streamed xml.

Comment: While I can't claim to have done it correctly, I have tried it.  I have yet to find a good example of reading a bare-bones XML file, adding nodes, and saving it back, using XmlWriter.  I suppose that's what I would need.

Comment: So you created a file, used resulting FileStream with XmlWriter, and still got out of memory?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I probably did not.  I think the problem I ran into is that I am trying to _insert_ nodes, and I couldn't find a way to get to a particular place in the XML with XmlWriter.  As I said...I likely used it wrong.

Comment: [`XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) *provides a fast, non-cached, forward-only way to generate streams or files that contain XML data*, so you cannot seek or write randomly.  Since you are trying to add child nodes to the root element, you might get some help from [Fastest way to add new node to end of an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849043)

Comment: Doesn't look like those solve the basic issue of not being able to avoid writing the _entire XML document_ using `XmlWriter`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott - there are some tricks from [Fastest way to add new node(s) to end of an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849043) to append new XML nodes to the file without having to read and rewrite the entire file.  They might work for you.

Comment: Do you need to insert data such that other data is shifted down or do you simply need to add data to the end? If you simply need to add data to the end then you can use lower-level I/O to position to the end and replace the end tags and such and add the data with the end tags at the end of them.

Comment: Since the consensus opinion seems to be "use XmlWriter", I think I will take a stab at refactoring the code to take the approach of writing the entire XML file in a single pass, instead of writing it in parts and trying to insert after-the-fact.