# Append instead of overwrite XML file DownloadFile in C#

Tags: c#, xml, webclient

We have a vendor API from which we are trying to download records using `WebClient` in C#. The problem is we can download only 500 recs at a time.

I'm trying to download data using a while loop. The loop is working and I'm able to download new records in each iteration, however, the XML file created is overwritten each time.

I would like to know how can this be avoided? Is there a way to append to existing XML file? If not, what are my options?

```
public bool FetchData()
{
    try
    {
        var success = true;
        var keepLooping = true;

        string DownloadFilePath = Globals.baseDir + @"VendorAPIData.xml";

        int UsersDownloaded = 0;
        var client = new Extensions.WebClient();

        string userProxy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserWebProxy"].ToString();
        var proxy = new WebProxy(userProxy);

        client.Proxy = proxy;
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        string authorizationHeaderValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorizationHeaderValue"].ToString();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeaderValue);
        string RestEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["getUsersEndpoint"].ToString();
        var downloadedXml = new XmlDocument();

        XmlNodeList nodes = null;

        while (keepLooping)
        {
            // Here it creates new file and downloads new nodes. 
            // Previous file is overwritten
            client.DownloadFile(RestEndpoint, DownloadFilePath);

            var theFile = new FileInfo(DownloadFilePath);

            if (theFile.Length == 0)
            {
                client.DownloadFile(RestEndpoint, DownloadFilePath);
            }

            downloadedXml.Load(DownloadFilePath);

            nodes = downloadedXml.GetElementsByTagName("PR_User");

            keepLooping = nodes.Count > 499 || nodes.Count == 0;
            UsersDownloaded += nodes.Count;

            Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} users from end point, {1} total.", nodes.Count, UsersDownloaded);
        }

        return success;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Eventually, I have insert this data into SQL Server, but I would like to download the data from API first. Here is sample VendorAPIData.xml. The PR_User gets repeated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PR_Users xmlns="xyz.API.RestSvcs" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <PR_User>
    <AccessUserGroupsIdList />
    <AttributeIdList>
      <PR_GuidId>
        <ID>30f33r2c-a096-43e1-9b26-2002f063e7b5</ID>
      </PR_GuidId>
      <PR_GuidId>
        <ID>ac3def18-381c-49af-9ff3-dd4abc4dcbe0</ID>
      </PR_GuidId>
      <PR_GuidId>
        <ID>ea250535-73e2-4df6-88cd-ea5eff27ae10</ID>
      </PR_GuidId>
    </AttributeIdList>
    <CrossReferences xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:Key>728de214-0708-gy54-c56v-44e788de764j</a:Key>
        <a:Value>1011158479</a:Value>
      </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:Key>728de214-342d-4787-c56v-44e788de764j</a:Key>
        <a:Value>RCJH345</a:Value>
      </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    </CrossReferences>
    <FirstName>ROBERT</FirstName>
    <Language i:nil="true" />
    <LanguageCulture i:nil="true" />
    <LastName>SMITH</LastName>
    <LocationIdList>
      <PR_GuidId>
        <ID>728d4567-0708-4787-c56v-44e788de764j</ID>
      </PR_GuidId>
    </LocationIdList>
    <Locked>false</Locked>
    <Login>RCJH345</Login>
    <PasswordHash i:nil="true" />
    <PermissionProfile>
      <Name>OFFICER</Name>
      <PermissionProfileId>
        <ID>728de214-0708-7833-c56v-44e784rr564j</ID>
      </PermissionProfileId>
      <Type>OFFICER</Type>
    </PermissionProfile>
    <PermissionProfileID>
      <ID>728de214-0708-6789-c56v-44e788de764j</ID>
    </PermissionProfileID>
    <PermissionProfileName>OFFICER</PermissionProfileName>
    <Port i:nil="true" />
    <ReportToID>
      <ID>728de214-4566-4787-c56v-44e788de764j</ID>
    </ReportToID>
    <ReportToName>LUKACH, BARBARA(BARB4356)</ReportToName>
    <Status>true</Status>
    <TagList />
    <UserGroupID>
      <ID>4bc2f32b-89c1-455b-6494-25dx76z76wd</ID>
    </UserGroupID>
    <UserGroupName>YTUF0987</UserGroupName>
    <UserId>
      <ID>546de214-0708-4787-c56v-767788de764j</ID>
    </UserId>
  </PR_User>
</PR_Users>
```

I'm new to XML. Please advise!

Comment: What type is `Extensions.WebClient`?

Comment: Well-formed XML documents are required to have one and only one [root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element) so are not well suited for applications that require incremental appending of content.  That's because you must **merge** rather than **append** new content.  What does your XML look like?  Do they all have the same root element?

Comment: See e.g. [Fastest way to add new node to end of an xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849043) for some possible workarounds.  Or you could just write a series of fragments and postprocess them into a single document afterwards.

Comment: Extenstions.WebClient class : System.Net.WebClient

Comment: @dbc, This is the structure of file 
<PR_Users xmlns="http://xyz.API.RestSvcs" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PR_User>
...
</PR_User>
</PR_Users>

Comment: XML  (and JSON) are unsuitable for storing open-ended streams of similar records. If this were my project I'd append the records to a plain old text file, perhaps using CSV to format them. Then, when I knew I had retrieved "all" the records I'd read the whole text file back and write the specified XML file.

Comment: It it were me, I'd read everything in to memory (if I were confident it would not become a resource issue) and then save a single file at the end. If it is significant data then I would save each file as they came in with different file names and process them all separately and save the final single file.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping the XML in memory.

Here's the basic code you need for this:

```
XNamespace ns = (XNamespace)"xyz.API.RestSvcs";
string content = client.DownloadString(RestEndpoint);
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(content);
    IEnumerable<XElement> descendents = document.Descendants(ns + "PR_User");
}
```

Comment: @Enign, I have added sample xml file structure. Basically <PR_User> forms one rec. I tried your code. descendents.Count returns 0. Please advise

Comment: @SilverFish - Your XML has a namespace You must use that to read it.

Comment: @SilverFish - I've updated my code to use the namespace.